# An regex example doesn't match the offical documentation result

Tags: mysql

From the MySQL documentation:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html (MySQL 8.0):

```
mysql> SELECT 'new*\n*line' REGEXP 'new\\*.\\*line';
+---------------------------------------+
| 'new*\n*line' REGEXP 'new\\*.\\*line' |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html (MySQL 5.7):

```
mysql> SELECT 'new*\n*line' REGEXP 'new\\*.\\*line';
+---------------------------------------+
| 'new*\n*line' REGEXP 'new\\*.\\*line' |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

But why I have `1` in MySQL 5.7 and `0` in MySQL 5.8 ?

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2212
Server version: 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT 'new*\n*line' REGEXP 'new\\*.\\*line';
+---------------------------------------+
| 'new*\n*line' REGEXP 'new\\*.\\*line' |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     1 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>


===========

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1107
Server version: 8.0.23 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
mysql> SELECT 'new*\n*line' REGEXP 'new\\*.\\*line';
+---------------------------------------+
| 'new*\n*line' REGEXP 'new\\*.\\*line' |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I am confused. Which should be the correct one? As for me, I think it matches..